# Can't access value of scope in AngularJS. Console log returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using ui-router for my application and nesting controllers within ui-view. My parent controller looks like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("discussoramaApp").controller("mainController", ["RestFullResponse", "Restangular", "localStorageService", "$scope", function(RestFullResponse, Restangular, localStorageService, $scope){

  var currentId = localStorageService.get("***");

  var user = Restangular.one("users", currentId);
  var Profile = user.get({}, {"Authorization" : localStorageService.get('***')}).then(function(profile) {
    $scope.profile = profile;
  });

}]);
```

And my child controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("discussoramaApp").controller("getTopicsController", ["RestFullResponse", "Restangular", "localStorageService", "$scope", function(RestFullResponse, Restangular, localStorageService, $scope){

  var topics = Restangular.all('topics');
  var allTopics = topics.getList({},{"Authorization" : localStorageService.get('***')}).then(function(topics){
    $scope.topics = topics;
  });

  console.log($scope); // this works
  console.log($scope.profile); // this returns undefined

}]);
```

The problem I'm having is getting the inherited $scope value for profile in the child controller. When I log $scope, profile is clearly visible in the console.

[image: $scope console log]

But when I try to log $scope.profile the console returns undefined. Any ideas?

Edit: Adding my ui-router config.

```
angular.module("discussoramaApp").config(
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/home');

    $stateProvider

      .state('main',{
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        requireLogin: true
      })

      .state('main.home',{
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.home.html',
        requireLogin: true,
        title: 'Home'
      });

  }
);
```

And the corresponding html files:

```
// main.html
<div ng-controller="mainController">

  <div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and the child html partial:

```
// main.home.html
<div ng-controller="getTopicsController">
  <div ng-repeat="topic in topics | filter:search">
    <a ui-sref="main.topic({id: topic.id})">{{ topic.topic_title }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: Solved this with a watcher set up like this in the child controller. Thanks @jonathanpglick and @Nix for the help.

```
$scope.$watch('profile', function(profile) {
  if(profile) {
    $window.document.title = "Discussorama | " + profile.user.name;
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post a blub that shows you `ui-router` config.

Comment: Added ui-router config and partials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.profile` is being set after an asynchronous request so I suspect that the second controller is being instantiated before `user.get()` returns and assigns a value to `$scope.profile`.

I think you'll want to set up a watcher (like `$scope.$watch('profile', function(profile) {});`) in the child controller so you can do things when the profile becomes available or changes.

Also, the reason you can see the `profile` key on `$scope` when you console log `$scope` can be explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7389177/325018.  You'll want to use `console.dir()` to get the current state of the object when it's called.

**UPDATE:**

I just realized you're using the ui-router and so there's an even easier way to do this.  The ui-router has a `resolve` object that you can use to dependency inject things like this into your controller.  Each resolve function just needs to return a value or a promise and it will be available for injection into the controller with resolve key name.  It would look like this for you:

```
angular.module("discussoramaApp").config(
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/home');

    $stateProvider

      .state('main',{
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        requireLogin: true,
        resolve: {
          profile: ['Restangular', 'localStorageService', function(Restangular , localStorageService) {
            var currentId = localStorageService.get("***");
            var user = Restangular.one("users", currentId);
            return user.get({}, {"Authorization" : localStorageService.get('***')});
          }
        }
      })

      .state('main.home',{
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.home.html',
        requireLogin: true,
        title: 'Home'
      });

  }
);

angular.module("discussoramaApp").controller("mainController", ["profile", "$scope", function(profile, $scope){
  $scope.profile = profile;
}]);
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I'm still a bit lost with watch and resolve. But I got it working. Need to read up on $scope in the docs a bit more I guess.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still having an issue with the watch. I know this is the right way to go just not sure how to implement it. I added some code to the end of my question to see if I'm doing it right.

Comment: I set up a watcher but I'm getting an error thrown. Could you take a look and see what the problem could be.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that initially the profile value will come in as `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have nested scope, doesn't mean it will  wait for `user.get()` to return before instantiating your nested `getTopicsController`.

Your issue is:

1. `mainController` controller initializes and calls `user.get()`
2. `getTopicsController` initializes and logs `console.log($scope.profile)`
3. The call to `user.get()` returns and then sets on scope.

This is a common issue, if you need to gaurantee that `$scope.profile` is set, use [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) or watch the variable.

I actually gave an example of how to do this earlier today:  [AngularJS $rootScope.$broadcast not working in app.run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363624/angularjs-rootscope-broadcast-not-working-in-app-run/23364913?noredirect=1#comment35788645_23364913)