# Angularjs $rootScope broadcast

Tags: angularjs

So I have this part of application structure, the behaviour I wan't to implement is: I want to fire up an event when user tries to access route without authorization, and then listen for that event on `LoginCtrl`

```
//First controller in application
<body data-ng-controller="GatewayCtrl">
    <div id="wrapper" data-ui-view="main"></div>
</body>

//then I have route which has `LoginCtrl` controller
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
            'main': {
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            }
        }
    });


app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('test-event');
    });
}]);


mdm.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('test-event', function () {
        console.log('event');
    });
}]);

mdm.controller('CounterCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('test-event', function () {
        console.log('event');
    });
}]);
```

Now the problem is that event is firing on `GatewayCtrl` controller but not `LoginCtrl`.

What is causing this issue and how could I resove it?

Comment: Can you post the `GatewayCtrl` code? Perhaps it is canceling the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what is happening here is that an angular controller must be belted to an element or a page (either by the ng-controller attribute or a predefined route - in your case "/login").

So, as per your example, the LoginCtrl is not instantiated yet, therefore it hasn't been able to add the listener to that event and, even further, once it got destroyed [the controller], the listener will be gone as well. So I don't think it's the best strategy to take.

You have a couple alternatives here:
**A)** Having this "listener" on a root controller which will be always instantiated throughout the app, such as an *AppController*, and/or
**B)** Using route.resolves to handle page authorization, there is a good example on this link: [AngularJS $rootScope.$broadcast not working in app.run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363624/angularjs-rootscope-broadcast-not-working-in-app-run);