# why this $scope.$on doesn`t work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angular, I wrote a test to get current user information. This is my code:

```
    var app = angular.module('gzmu', ["ngRoute",'chart.js']);
    app.run(function ($rootScope, $http) {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'datacon/user_info.php',

        }).success(function (response) {
                  //response is ready
            $rootScope.$broadcast("userinfo", response[0]);



        })
    });
    app.controller('data', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
        $scope.username='';
        $scope.$on("userinfo",
            function (event, msg) {
//this function not work every time,when i reload the page,no alert is pop out

                if(msg){
                    $scope.username = msg.user;
                    console.log($scope.username)
                    alert($scope.usernamea)
                }
                else{
                    alert(msg);
                }

            });
    }）;
```

If I want to ask if I want the `$scope.username` to be setup in `$on`, what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS $rootScope.$broadcast not working in app.run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363624/angularjs-rootscope-broadcast-not-working-in-app-run)

Comment: When you reload the page, do you see the outgoing request? It could be a cache problem ...

Comment: if you are using $rootScope.$broadcast("userinfo", response[0]); then you should use $rootScope..$on("userinfo",
            function (event, msg)